# Does chess.com analysis board use my own CPU?

Tags: engines

Lichess analysis board uses my own cpu so I am just curious if chess.com also uses my own cpu.I have tried searching but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: Try looking into task manager, if running engine uses cpu resources.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. It uses stockfish.js, the Javascript port of Stockfish, which can run on web browsers. You can see stockfish.js mentioned somewhere on the chess.com analysis board. Also, I can tell that the computer fan starts working harder when I run an analysis, and looking at the "top" command shows that the web browser is using 100% CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Local board analysis definitely use your own CPUs, running the Javascript version of Stockfish. However, the deeper server analysis uses their own computing clusters.

Same with Lichess.